# Possible HeroCard or Azure Test Web Chat Image caching issue

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, adaptive-cards

I am experiencing what i think may be a caching problem with HeroCards on the Web Chat Test emulator in the Azure Portal. Since Cortana does not support AdaptiveCards, to fully debug my bot I am temporarily rendering the AdaptiveCard as an image and then adding the image to a HeroCard. I then add the HeroCard as an attachment in the reply.

What I am finding is that if I type the first question (A) in the Azure Test in Web Chat the correct image is displayed in the emulator, however if i ask a different question (B), the same card is displayed. I can see that the image is changing in my cached images folder but cannot work out why the card is always the same.

I have added a time stamp to the card title to prove that its not the same card. Here is my code from question A. The code for question B differs only in the AdaptiveCard generated.

```
    SingleDayCompactCard card = new SingleDayCompactCard(p1, p2, p3);
    // Start of temporary code
    Activity reply = activity.CreateReply();
    reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
    Attachment attachment = await AdaptiveCardToHeroAttachment(card);
    reply.Attachments.Add(attachment);
    // end of temporary code - remove when Cortana supports Adaptive cards
    ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
    await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);


    async Task<Attachment> AdaptiveCardToHeroAttachment(AdaptiveCard card)
    {
        AdaptiveHostConfig hostConfig = new AdaptiveHostConfig()
        {
            SupportsInteractivity = false
        };

        string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath(@"\cache\temp.png");

        // Create a renderer
        AdaptiveCardRenderer renderer = new AdaptiveCardRenderer(hostConfig);
        RenderedAdaptiveCardImage raci = null;
        try
        {
            AdaptiveCardParseResult parseResult = AdaptiveCard.FromJson(card.ToJson());
            AdaptiveCard c = parseResult.Card;
            raci =
                await renderer.RenderCardToImageAsync(c, true);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

        using (System.IO.FileStream output = new System.IO.FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            await raci.ImageStream.CopyToAsync(output);
            await output.FlushAsync();
            output.Close();
        }

        HeroCard hero = new HeroCard();
        hero.Title = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        hero.Images.Add(new CardImage("http://localhost:3979/cache/temp.png"));
        return hero.ToAttachment();
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible that the browser itself is caching the http://localhost:3979/cache/temp.png ?  Have you tried turning off your browser's cache?

Comment: You could also use a base64 encoded image.  There's an example of that here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4037#issuecomment-357362856

Answer (score 0):

Huge thanks Eric

Turning off the browser cache did not work but the second suggestion of using a base64 encoded image did the trick.

I deleted this block of code and replaced it by the code in the link for the base64 encoded image

```
        HeroCard hero = new HeroCard();
        hero.Title = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        hero.Images.Add(new CardImage("http://localhost:3979/cache/temp.png"));
        return hero.ToAttachment();
```

So this line must be the culprit

CardImage("http://localhost:3979/cache/temp.png"));

Thanks again